# Why some of emails which sent by Google Apps Script with Form-submission trigger send twice?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, form-submit

I've noticed my sent email from Google App Script with Form-Submission Triggered and found that 3 in almost 300 of my emails are sent twice!
I have no idea about this and here is what i wrote.

```
function emailAsExcel(spreadsheetId,subject,message,fileName,link) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var fileId = ss.getId();
  var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:D2').getValues();

  var url           = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+fileId+'/export?format=xlsx';
  var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  })
  var blobs   =  response.getBlob().setName(fileName+'.xlsx');

  var picblobs = DriveApp.getFileById(getIdFromUrl(link)).getBlob().setName(fileName + '.jpg');

  var sender = "xxx@gmail.com"+","+ "yyy@gmail.com";

  var email = sender;

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message,{attachments: [blobs, picblobs]});  

}

function genFile(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('yyyyy');

  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(1,9,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(String).length;
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  var date = sheet.getRange('A'+lastRow).getValue();
  var name = sheet.getRange('J'+lastRow).getValue();
  var surname = sheet.getRange('K'+lastRow).getValue();
  var number = sheet.getRange('E'+lastRow).getValue();
  var prov = sheet.getRange('F'+lastRow).getValue();
  var brand = sheet.getRange('G'+lastRow).getValue();
  var link = sheet.getRange('I'+lastRow).getValue();  

  var subject = name+'_'+surname;

  var message = 
      'customer fullname : '+ name +' '+surname+'\n'
      +'num : '+ number + prov+'\n'
      +'bra : '+ brand +'\n'

  var fileName = name+ ' ' +surname;
  Logger.log(link); 

  var destination = DriveApp.getFileById('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa').makeCopy().getId();
  var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destination);
  var newSheet = newFile.getSheetByName('bbbbbbbbb');

  newSheet.getRange('A2').setValue(date);
  newSheet.getRange('B2').setValue(name+' '+surname);
  newSheet.getRange('C2').setValue(number);
  newSheet.getRange('D2').setValue(prov);
  newSheet.getRange('E2').setValue(brand);
  newFile.setName(fileName);

  emailAsExcel(destination,subject,message,fileName,link);

}

function getIdFromUrl(url) { return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); }
  genFile();
}
```

I try to figure it out but I still do not know what happened, so I need you guys' advice. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This likely happens when you (or another Google account that has access to this script) has created multiple triggers.

Go to https://script.google.com/home/triggers, choose your project and remove any duplicate onSubmit triggers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!. I'll check with my colleague and remove those duplicate.            Is it possible that submitter have poor internet  connection so they hit submit button twice?